# Group or world writable directory

Tags: shell, directory

I'm trying to use a script but get the following error:

```
Directory is group or world writeable.
This is insecure, since any malicious user can trick you to write
newly generated private key into his file. Please, restrict directory
rights to permit directory writes only to yourself or choose another
directory.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You will have to be more clear on what you are asking. Are you trying to write a script that outputs which directories are group or world writable? Or do you want to know how to change directory permissions so the directory is not group or world writable?

Comment: this script generate private sertificate, i think it need protected directory

Answer (score 1):

`chmod 0700 /path/to/directory`

This command will make `directory` readable, writable, and executable only to the user who owns it. You probably don't want other users to have read access to a directory that holds a private certificate.